# Memory overwritten after allocating array of structs

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-leaks, memory-management

I'm trying to allocate memory for a array of structures, but after it is allocated a int that is passed in the function is set to '0'... The problem is gone when i increase the size of the array. Here is my code:

```
wchar_t* ISTFallSensor::JSON_EventLog(int nRecords) {
wchar_t* returnstring = new wchar_t[8192]; memset( returnstring, 0, 8192 * sizeof(TCHAR) ); 

HINSTANCE hIstDLL;
DWORD (*IST_Open)(TCHAR *, HANDLE *)                                        = 0;
DWORD (*IST_Close)(HANDLE)                                                  = 0;
DWORD (*IST_GetMotionEventLogCount)(HANDLE, DWORD, PDWORD)                  = 0;
DWORD (*IST_GetMotionEventLogRecords)(HANDLE, IST_LOG_RECORD[], int, PINT)  = 0;

hIstDLL = LoadLibrary(L"ISTAPI32.dll");
if(hIstDLL && nRecords > 0 ){
    IST_Open                        = (DWORD (__cdecl *)(TCHAR *, HANDLE *))GetProcAddress(hIstDLL, L"IST_Open");
    IST_Close                       = (DWORD (__cdecl *)(HANDLE))GetProcAddress(hIstDLL, L"IST_Close");
    IST_GetMotionEventLogCount      = (DWORD (__cdecl *)(HANDLE, DWORD, PDWORD))GetProcAddress(hIstDLL, L"IST_GetMotionEventLogCount");
    IST_GetMotionEventLogRecords    = (DWORD (__cdecl *)(HANDLE, IST_LOG_RECORD[], int, PINT))GetProcAddress(hIstDLL, L"IST_GetMotionEventLogRecords");

    HANDLE  phIst = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    DWORD openStatus = IST_Open( _T("IST1:"), &phIst );

    if ( openStatus == IST_ERROR_SUCCESS ) {
        DWORD dropsD; IST_GetMotionEventLogCount(phIst, FREEFALL, &dropsD);
        int drops = (int)dropsD;
        if ( nRecords > drops ) nRecords = drops; if ( nRecords > 32 ) nRecords = 32;
        int pnRecords = 0; 
        IST_LOG_RECORD eventlog[32] = {0};

        DWORD getStatus = IST_GetMotionEventLogRecords(phIst, eventlog, drops, &pnRecords);
```

The last function gets a list of events and uses the given array to store that info. When the function returns the array is filled correcly, but the nRecords value is overwritten by '0'.

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a memory overflow.

You adjust the variable `nRecords` so that it won't exceed 32, which is the maximum number of `IST_LOG_RECORD` that fit the `eventlog` array.

However you don't use it in the call to `IST_GetMotionEventLogRecords`. Instead you use `drops`, which equals to `dropsD`, which is **not** limited to 32.

Just use `nRecords` instead of `drops`:

```
DWORD getStatus = IST_GetMotionEventLogRecords(phIst, eventlog, nRecords, &pnRecords);
```